# Split word in column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple columns in R. I want to split the "age" column into two column, each with one string in it.

```
         fas       value age colony
   1:  C12:0 0.002221915  LO   7_13
   2:  C13:0 0.000770179  LO   7_13
   3:  C14:0 0.004525352  LO   7_13
   4:  C15:0 0.000738928  LO   7_13
   5: C16:1a 0.002964627  LO   7_13
```

Output:

```
         fas           value size age colony
       1:  C12:0 0.002221915    L   O   7_13
       2:  C13:0 0.000770179    L   O   7_13
       3:  C14:0 0.004525352    L   O   7_13
       4:  C15:0 0.000738928    L   O   7_13
       5: C16:1a 0.002964627    L   O   7_13
```

I tried:

```
data_frame<-str_split_fixed(df$age, "", 2)
```

Comment: The result of your attempt (`str_split_fixed(df$age, "", 2)`) indeed splits the string correctly. As you notice the result is a two column matrix. Although it _can_ be added to the original data, you make your life a bit easier by using `data.table::tstrsplit`: `DT[ , c("size", "age") := tstrsplit(age, "")]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With base R:

```
df$size <- substr(df$age,1,1)
df$age  <- substr(df$age,2,2)
```

And to get the result in the column order you specified:

```
df[,c("fas","value","age","size","colony")]
     fas       value age size colony
1  C12:0 0.002221915   O    L   7_13
2  C13:0 0.000770179   O    L   7_13
3  C14:0 0.004525352   O    L   7_13
4  C15:0 0.000738928   O    L   7_13
5 C16:1a 0.002964627   O    L   7_13
```

Answer (score 8):

Since your data appears to be `data.table`, I'll infer that package is loaded. However, `strcapture` is base R and will return a `data.frame` with the two columns (names/classes based on the third argument, `proto=`).

```r
strcapture("(.)(.)", DT$age, list(size="", age=""))
#   size age
# 1    L   O
# 2    L   O
# 3    L   O
# 4    L   O
# 5    L   O

library(data.table)
DT[, c("size", "age") := strcapture("(.)(.)", age, list(size="", age="")) ]
DT
#       fas       value    age colony   size
#    <char>       <num> <char> <char> <char>
# 1:  C12:0 0.002221915      O   7_13      L
# 2:  C13:0 0.000770179      O   7_13      L
# 3:  C14:0 0.004525352      O   7_13      L
# 4:  C15:0 0.000738928      O   7_13      L
# 5: C16:1a 0.002964627      O   7_13      L
```

You may choose to be more defensive in the pattern, shifting to `"^(.)(.)$"`, which should not match anything outside of our 2-char expectation.

---

Data

```r
DT <- data.table::fread(text="
   fas       value age colony
 C12:0 0.002221915  LO   7_13
 C13:0 0.000770179  LO   7_13
 C14:0 0.004525352  LO   7_13
 C15:0 0.000738928  LO   7_13
C16:1a 0.002964627  LO   7_13")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sub`and backreference:

```
df$age <- sub("(^\\w)(\\w$)", "\\1", df$age)
df$size <- sub("(^\\w)(\\w$)", "\\2", df$age)
```

Answer (score 7):

The tidyverse solution uses `tidyr::separate()`:

```r
library("tidyr")

tbl <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
   fas       value age colony
 C12:0 0.002221915  LO   7_13
 C13:0 0.000770179  LO   7_13
 C14:0 0.004525352  LO   7_13
 C15:0 0.000738928  LO   7_13
C16:1a 0.002964627  LO   7_13")

separate(tbl, age, c("age", "size"), 1)
#>      fas       value age size colony
#> 1  C12:0 0.002221915   L    O   7_13
#> 2  C13:0 0.000770179   L    O   7_13
#> 3  C14:0 0.004525352   L    O   7_13
#> 4  C15:0 0.000738928   L    O   7_13
#> 5 C16:1a 0.002964627   L    O   7_13
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To split the column `age` (contains 2 characters "LO") you can

1. remove last character `gsub('.{1}$', '', df$age)` you get "L"
2. remove first character `sub('.', '', df$age)` you get "O"

```
df %>% 
  mutate(size = gsub('.{1}$', '', df$age), # remove last character 
         age = sub('.', '', df$age)) # remove first character
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `tidyr::separate` (which is usually the way to go here), we can also use `tidyr::extract`:

```
tbl %>% tidyr::extract(age,
                       into = c('age', 'size'),
                       regex = "(.)(.)",
                       remove = TRUE)

     fas       value age size colony
1  C12:0 0.002221915   L    O   7_13
2  C13:0 0.000770179   L    O   7_13
3  C14:0 0.004525352   L    O   7_13
4  C15:0 0.000738928   L    O   7_13
5 C16:1a 0.002964627   L    O   7_13
```